# Adding to PATH using Spyder via Anaconda

Tags: python, path, latex, anaconda

I need to add the latex folder to my python `PATH` in order to render plots in latex font. I **cannot** figure out how to permanently add the latex file path to the python `PATH`. I can get it to add by running:

```
import os

os.environ["PATH"] = '/anaconda3/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-darwin'
```

but as soon as I restart Spyder it everts back to the old path.

How can I permanently add

```
/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-darwin'
```

to the python path?

Also, I have tried to add it to the .bach_profile by modifying it as follows:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-darwin:/anaconda3/bin:$PATH":
```

but it seems that python isn't looking here when it looks at its `PATH`.

Running `print(os.getenv("PATH"))` returns:

```
/anaconda3/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

no matter what I do to the `.bash_profile` file.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using MacOS X and ran into the same issue.
How I got around this problem is launching Spyder from Terminal, just by typing in your Terminal (assuming that the path to spyder is given):

```
$ spyder
```

By doing this, the environment variables should be inherited from Terminal (i.e. /.bashrc and /.bash_profile, etc).

Hope this helps.

Atsushi